# Creating shortcut inside windows start menu

Tags: c++, winapi, shortcut, access-denied, startmenu

I can't create a shortcut or even create a folder inside `C:\\ProgramData\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Start Menu\\` and get an "**Access is denied**" error in both cases. I am using C++(WinAPI) and am interested in creating a shortcut inside that folder. Code for creating shortcut is working perfectly for other locations(for example for creating shortcuts on Desktop). How can I workaround this error?

Comment: Can you manually create a folder in that location as your own user?

Comment: Yes, in Windows explorer there is "New->Folder" menu item in windows context menu, however that command required Administrative privileges.

Comment: "that command required Administrative privileges" - so, no, then. Try running your program with admin privileges.

Comment: What does the documentation on MSDN say?

Comment: Don't write to `%ProgramData%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu` directly. Use `CSIDL_COMMON_STARTMENU`/`FOLDERID_CommonStartMenu` (all users) or `CSIDL_STARTMENU`/`FOLDERID_StartMenu` (current user) to get a suitable path, then create your custom folder underneath it.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Could you elaborate on how? Maybe propose a separate answer? Does this help bypass the admin rights issue?

Comment: @Enigma look at `SHGetFolderPath()` and `SHGetKnownFolderPath()`. And no, this doesn't bypass the admin issue. You still need admin rights to create a folder/file in a "common" location for all users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Writing to the All-users start menu requires UAC rights. So, you'll need to run your application as administrator. Or just use the current-user start menu
"C:\Users\[CurrentUser]\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu"

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string StartMenuLocation=
    (string)getenv("HOMEDRIVE")+"\\Users\\"+(string)getenv("USERNAME")+"\\AppData\\Roaming\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Start Menu";
    cout<<StartMenuLocation;
    cin.get();
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is based on undocumented internals, and not guaranteed to work. In fact, it doesn't even work for all supported versions of Windows. The [comment by Remy Lebeau](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35673086/creating-shortcut-inside-windows-start-menu/37418624#comment59027217_35673086) explains, how to do it properly.

Comment: @xxx You can also considered the suggestion of not suggesting an answer based undocumented behavior.  You should improve your answer.

Comment: If you feel like fixing things, you should start with your proposed answer. You have all the information you need to come up with a robust solution, that works across all versions of Windows.